# Simplified VSTS Work Item forms for some teams?

Tags: azure-devops, agile

Or developers need the Work Item forms as designed for our agile process, but we'd like our regular users to be able to add new bugs and user stories using a simplified form, where a lot of fields are removed and some have team specific default values.

How can this be done?

The closest match I've found so far is templates, where field defaults can be defined, but the form that's used/displayed is still the large cluttered one. Being able to use the template link to land directly on a pre-filled form is a step in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps allows you to modify your process template and add new work items to your project. You can find the documentation to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-wit?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

Go to Organization settings for your account --> Process --> Create an inherited process from your process template --> New Work Item Type.

You can then define the fields you want and the layout of the template.

Something else that could be useful in your scenario is the [Test and Feedback Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/request-stakeholder-feedback?view=vsts). This is a simple browser plugin that lets users explore feedback requests and file comments and bugs.

Comment: I assume that we'd change work item type to the full fledged type when we review the submitted item. Not exactly what I was looking for, but maybe close enough. Thanks!

Comment: @KjellRilbe That''s possible! There is a change work item flow in Azure DevOps. If the fields are available in both work items and the states map you can change one item into another. That allows you to start simple and morph the item into a full user story on your backlog.See https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser#change-type for more information